# For loop being skipped in c-file when run from bash

Tags: c, bash, text-files

I am running a c file which generates data and writes it to text file. Below is a bash script which runs this file multiple times for different parameters. When I run the c code by itself there are no problems. When I run it with the script below no data is saved to the text file (they are still created). It seems to be that the for loop, which the printing to the text file lies in, is being skipped (ascertained by placing print statements before and after this for loop).

```
#!/bin/bash 

make studentt_sampler

# arguments to pass to ./studentt_sampler
no_samples=5
nu=3.0
mu=1.0
sigma=1.0
data_files=("data_file_0p01.txt" "data_file_0p1.txt" "data_file_1.txt" "data_file_10.txt")
proposal_sigma=(0.01,0.1,1.0,10.0)

# arguments to pass to post_process.py
figure_files=("chain_0p01.pdf" "chain_0p1.pdf" "chain_1.pdf" "chain_10.pdf")


for i in `seq 0 3`;
do
    #echo ${data_files[$i]}
    ./studentt_sampler no_samples nu mu sigma "${data_files[$i]}" "${proposal_sigma[$i]}" &
    # ./post_process.py echo ${data_files[$i]} echo ${figure_files[$i]}

done

wait
```

The main function of the c file is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Initialization */
    const gsl_rng_type * T;
    gsl_rng * r;


    /* set iteration variables and the order of the student-t distribution
     * from the command line arguments */
    int i, itr = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* parameters of student t distributions */
    double nu = atof(argv[2]); 
    double mu = atof(argv[3]);
    double sigma = atof(argv[4]);

    /* store the parameters in param_type struct */
    struct param_type params = {nu,mu,sigma};

    /* open text file for writing  and make sure it works*/

    printf("%s\n",argv[5]);
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[5], "w"); 

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* allocate memory for generator and set its seed */
    r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937); 
    gsl_rng_set(r,1); 

    /* Start initial value */
    double x_cur = 1.0; 
    double proposal_sigma = atof(argv[6]);
    double alpha;
    double x_prop;
    int accept; /* keep track of acceptance rate */
    double u; /* to make decision of accept proposal or not */
    double accept_prob;

    /* Start the MCMC */
    for (i=0;i<itr;i++) {
        printf("here!!!\n");
        /* propose a new x */
        x_prop = gsl_ran_gaussian(r,proposal_sigma) + x_cur;

        /* Calculate acceptance probability */
        accept_prob = lklhood(x_prop, &params)/lklhood(x_cur, &params);
        alpha = GSL_MIN(1.0,accept_prob);

        /* Accept or not, decide */
        u = gsl_ran_flat(r,0.0,1.0);
        if (u < alpha) {
            x_cur = x_prop;
            accept = 1;
        }/* print to data file */
        else {
            accept = 0;
        }
        fprintf(f," %.5f %i\n",x_cur,accept);
    } 

    /* Clean up time */
    fclose(f);


    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you forgot the `$` in the variables you supply to the program, i.e. shouldn't it be:

```
./studentt_sampler $no_samples $nu $mu $sigma "${data_files[$i]}" "${proposal_sigma[$i]}" &
```

Comment: Yup, I'm a fool. I appreciate your help chw21.